Py2App doesn't work in deployment mode but did work in alias mode
I've been trying to turn my python project into a standalone Mac App. I'm using Python 3.10.5 and Py2App 0.28.7 and currently running MacOS Monterey. I did follow the documentation on their website and got my standalone app to work when creating it using the developing alias mode. However when I try to create the standalone app in deployment mode, I'm getting the error below.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

I have tried to installed chardet using pip install but it didn't work either.

try installing it with python(version) -m pip install chardet.
So if you are running python3.12 it would be
python3.12 -m pip install chardet

